# Calculation in django model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Here is my models:

```
class Consignment(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
    package_ammount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    image = models.ImageField()
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.brand.name + ' ' + str(self.volume) + ' liters'

class ProductPackage(models.Model):
    consignment = models.ForeignKey(Consignment)
    ammount_in_package = models.IntegerField()
    total_volume = consignment.volume*ammount_in_package
    total_width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    total_height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    total_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    package_price = consignment.price*ammount_in_package
```

The problem is with `package_price` field. It calculates `package_price` that is based on `price` of `Consignment` model and `ammount_in_package` of`ProductPackage` model. But this code throws and error when `makemigrations` `ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'volume'`
And will `package_price` will be showing in `admin` page? I don't need it, because it calculates automatically, admin doesn't have to be allowed to change it.

Answer (score 2):

`package_price` should be a property like this:

```
class ProductPackage(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def package_price(self):
        return self.consignment.price * self.ammount_in_package
```

You can show this property in admin by adding it to the `list_display`.  And, of course, it is not editable in admin :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in `get`/`set` methods or consider using a `property` (which I would *not* advise anyway):

```
def get_package_price(self):
    return consignment.price*ammount_in_package

package_price = property(_get_package_price)
```

See [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/) for more.